# Interpreting javascript toSource()

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I get the following when I call response.toSource() having made a query to a google spreadsheet.

```
({
    ej: "0.6",
    Oe: "ok",
    gb: [],
    hb: [],
    Cg: "407260946",
    g: {
        zb: "0.6",
        z: [{
            id: "B",
            label: "",
            type: "string",
            pattern: ""}],
        D: [{
            c: [{
                v: "\"My data\""}]}],
        Na: null
    }
})​
```

I wish to access the string "My data" and store it in a var, how do I do this?

Comment: `var myData = response["g"]["D"][0]["c"][0]["v"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, "My data" is a value to the key `v` in an array which is a value to the key `c` which is stored in an array which is a value to the key `D` which is stored in an object with the key `g`. So it's

```
var myData = response["g"]["D"][0]["c"][0]["v"];
```

Comment: Thank! Is there a way to get the type of response so that I can check for online documentation?

Comment: @Baz: You'll have to provide the context of the response. I have no idea where this object comes from. How did you get this response? What function did you call? Which API did you use? Provide this information in your original question.